# Merge two datasets

Tags: r, dplyr

I create a node list as follows:

```
name <- c("Joe","Frank","Peter")
city <- c("New York","Detroit","Maimi")
age <- c(24,55,65)
node_list <- data.frame(name,age,city)

node_list    
   name age     city
1   Joe  24 New York
2 Frank  55  Detroit
3 Peter  65    Maimi
```

Then I create an edge list as follows:

```
from <- c("Joe","Frank","Peter","Albert")
to <- c("Frank","Albert","James","Tony")
to_city <- c("Detroit","St. Louis","New York","Carson City")
edge_list <- data.frame(from,to,to_city)

edge_list
    from     to     to_city
1    Joe  Frank     Detroit
2  Frank Albert   St. Louis
3  Peter  James    New York
4 Albert   Tony Carson City
```

Notice that the names in the node list and edge list do not overlap 100%. I want to create a master node list of all the names, capturing city information as well. This is my dplyr attempt to do this:

```
new_node <- edge_list %>%
  gather("from_to", "name", from, to) %>%
  distinct(name) %>%
  full_join(node_list)

new_node
  name age     city
1    Joe  24 New York
2  Frank  55  Detroit
3  Peter  65    Maimi
4 Albert  NA     <NA>
5  James  NA     <NA>
6   Tony  NA     <NA>
```

I need to figure out how to add to_city information. What do I need to add to my dplyr code to make this happen? Thanks.

Comment: What would the master list look like if there are multiple edges starting from the same node? Is that possible?

You could just do a `left_join(new_node, edge_list, by = c('name' = 'from')` if I understand correctly

Comment: Yes, one can have multiple edges from same node. The left join does not work as you expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Join twice, once on `to` and once on `from`, with the irrelevant columns subsetted out:

```r
library(dplyr)

node_list <- data_frame(name = c("Joe", "Frank", "Peter"),
                        city = c("New York", "Detroit", "Maimi"),
                        age = c(24, 55, 65))

edge_list <- data_frame(from = c("Joe", "Frank", "Peter", "Albert"),
                        to = c("Frank", "Albert", "James", "Tony"),
                        to_city = c("Detroit", "St. Louis", "New York", "Carson City"))

node_list %>% 
    full_join(select(edge_list, name = to, city = to_city)) %>% 
    full_join(select(edge_list, name = from))
#> Joining, by = c("name", "city")
#> Joining, by = "name"
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   name   city          age
#>   <chr>  <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 Joe    New York      24.
#> 2 Frank  Detroit       55.
#> 3 Peter  Maimi         65.
#> 4 Albert St. Louis     NA 
#> 5 James  New York      NA 
#> 6 Tony   Carson City   NA
```

In this case the second join doesn't do anything because everybody is already included, but it would insert anyone who only existed in the `from` column.